# Best practice for ordering a list with one of four rules

Tags: java, android, performance, list

I have a range of objects which needs to be ordered with a rule. But I need to be able to switch the rules however I have a limited set of ordering rules. Which data structure would be the best choice for that?

As an example I have this class:

```
class Test {
    public final int amount;
    public final int cost;
    public final String name;
    public final int whatever;
    // ...

    // TODO: add a constructor to set the fields :-)
}
```

How can I store those fields to order them by amount, cost, name or whatever. But just one of that rules.

I could imagine to use an `ArrayList` or a `HashSet` where I call the sort function with a custom `Comparator`. But I cannot imagine that this is efficiency. I think this is important on a mobile device. What is a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use an `Set` for sorting, as it does not have any order. How every the concept of having `List` and custom `Comparator<T>` is reasonable.

You should go with that solution and do not care about performance at this point. If you will be not satisfied from gained result then try to came up with better solution.

The best solution is reading data from storage in proper order. I do not know how your app store that structure. Therefore I can not help you with that. But implement the comparable solution and you will see that is not so bad.

What is important on mobile device is memory usage. If your application will use lot of those sorting operation you could create the Comparators as enums so they will be loaded only once and in addition can simplify the code

```
private enum  TestComparator implements Comparator<Test> {
 BY_NAME {

    @Override
    public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {

       //We validate first against null

       return o1n.name.compareTo(o2.name);

    }               
  }
 BY_WHATEVER{

    @Override
    public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {

       //We validate first against null
      return (o1.whatever<o2.whatever ? -1 : (o1.whatever==o2.whatever ? 0 : 1));
    }               
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
class Test {
public final int amount;
public final int cost;
public final String name;
public final int whatever;
// ...

// TODO: add a constructor to set the fields :-)

    class TestAmountComparator implements Comparator<Test> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Test t1, Test t2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(t1.amount).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(t2.amount))          
        }
    }

    class TestCostComparator implements Comparator<Test> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Test t1, Test t2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(t1.cost).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(t2.cost))          
        }
    }
```

}

Store your Test objects in `ArrayList` (or any other Collection) and then sort them this way:

```
List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>(myTest); //your Test list
//sorting
Collections.sort(list, new TestAmountComparator()); //sort by amount
Collections.sort(list, new TestCostComparator()); //sort by cost
```

Comment: it is more efficient to compare "cost" as Integer.compare(t1.cost, t2.cost); same for "amount"

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferred implementing **Comparable interface** and implement **compareTo** method in the class. It provides consistence behaviour of sorting across different data structures.
In this case **Comparator interface** will be used only if special sorting is required.

```
class Test implements Comparable {
    public final int amount;
    public final int cost;
    public final String name;
    public final int whatever;
    // ...
    //add equals ,hashcode, and compareTo method in the class...
    // TODO: add a constructor to set the fields :-)
}
```

You can use TreeSet if instances are unique and comparable is implemented. Else otherwise you have to use lists and order them with Collection.sort function.

You can decide the DS based on access use. If you want to access the elements in sequence use LinkedList else user ArrayList

Comment: The hint with TreeSet is Ok. But not for this question, as OP require to use different Comparators on the same model.

Comment: Actually TreeSet sorted by eg amount can have instances with the same amount if compareTo returns 1 when t1.amount == t2.amount

Comment: There is java.util.PriorityQueue, it's also sorted but can hold duplicates

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev Set can only have unique objects. if 2 objects of are equal then second object will not be appended to the set. implementation of compareTo must depend on implementer...

Comment: If you want to add duplicate instances then set will discard the second entry.

Comment: @Vash I think you are write. But it holds good to deal on type of sorting. :)

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
class Test3 implements Comparable<Test3> {
    public int amount;
    //...

    Comparator<Test3> comparator;

    public void setComparator(Comparator<Test3> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Test3 o) {
        return comparator.compare(this, o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can use TreeSet without losing duplicates:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

    public class Test {
        int amount;

        Test(int amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            Comparator<Test> c = new Comparator<Test>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Test o1, Test o2) {
                    if (o1.amount >= o2.amount) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    return -1;
                }
            };
            TreeSet<Test> s = new TreeSet<Test>(c);
            s.add(new Test(2));
            s.add(new Test(1));
            s.add(new Test(1));
            for (Test t : s) {
                System.out.println(t.amount);
            }

        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
1
1
2
```

Comment: Your comparator do nor return valid result if amount are equal.

Comment: But this is why equal objects stay in TreeSet, the whole thing works correctly.